LaTeX Chemical \usepackage{chemfig} Clipping/Structural Issue
I have been writing a new LaTeX project that has to show chemical formula. When I enter in the code, the CHOSO_3 is clipping inside each other as shown:

Here is the basic code I have used:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Chemical Structures and Formulas, colframe=black, colback=white!95!yellow]
\textbf{Propene (\ce{C3H6})}: \\

\chemfig{*6((=CH-CH3)-CH=)}

\textbf{Isopropanol (\ce{C3H8O})}: \\

\chemfig{*6((=CH-CH3)-CH(OH)-CH3)}

\textbf{Isopropyl Sulfate (\ce{(CH3)2CHOSO3H})}: \\

\chemfig{*6((=CH-CH3)-CH(OSO3H)-CH3)}

\textbf{Ether Byproduct (\ce{(CH3)2CH-O-CH(CH3)2})}: \\

\chemfig{*6((=CH-CH3)-CH(O)-CH(CH3)-CH3)}
\end{tcolorbox}

Apologies for excluding forced document structures. What do I need to do to fix this?

Note that you did not make the isopropyl phosphate structure. Your molecule has one extra CH      \chemfig{H_3C-[:330]CH(-[6,,1]O-[0]S(=[2]O)(=[6]O)-[0]OH)-[:30]CH3}

You opened a parenthesis, but you didn't put a chemical bond in it
Use
\chemfig{*6((=CH-CH3)-CH(-[6,,1]O-[0]S(=[2]O)(=[6]O)-[0]OH)-CH3)}


